# In-browser video (de)coding and processing

Tags: java, silverlight, flash, web, video-processing

For our web app we need some (preferably) client side video processing.

I think of the following workflow:

1. ask a user for a video file
2. decode it
3. do some processing on selected frames
4. combine these frames to the new video
5. encode it
6. upload it to the server
7. play it to our users

Reasons to do this client side:

1. output video is much smaller, so we have to upload less
2. video processing is too costly for the server, we prefer to use client's CPU

It is OK to install something once but then everything should work as an ordinary web app.

I've spent few days googling, but it is just too much to digest. So I ask for help.

Here are my findings/assumptions/questions.

1. Is there a simple way to do it with Flash?

   1.1. Can access user-selected file from local file system

   1.2. Has some decoders built-in, but these are rather specific and do NOT cover common video formats

   1.3. Can NOT use locally installed codecs

   1.4. It is impractical to implement codecs in ActionScript, so there are no such libraries

   1.5. Can process frames

   1.6. Has built-in coder(s)
2. Is there a simple way to do it with Silverlight?

   2.1. Can access user-selected file from local file system

   2.2. Has some decoders built-in, but these are rather specific and do NOT cover common video formats

   2.3. Can NOT use locally installed codecs from in-browser sandbox

   2.4. Can bring external executable (ffmpeg) to the in-browser sandbox but can NOT run it

   2.5. Can only use DLLs specifically built for Silverlight runtime inside in-browser sandbox, so ffmpeg proxy (COM?) and alikes are of NO use

   2.6. Can be right-click-installed from web page and maybe #2.3, #2.4 or #2.5 will work, but this will NOT make on-page app work, user will need to run it separately outside browser

   2.7. It is OK to implement codecs natively (port ffmpeg?), but I was not able to find such a pack

   2.8. Can process frames

   2.9. Has built-in coder(s)
3. Is there a simple way to do it with Java?

   3.1. Can access user-selected file from local file system

   3.2. JMF has basic codecs built-in

   3.3. Jffmpeg could add more codecs

   3.4. Can process frames
4. Is there something else that could do the job?

Looks like due to #1.2, #1.3 and #1.4 Flash is not an option.

Looks like Silverlight could do the trick if only there exists natively implemented codecs pack.

Java looks most promising.
Before diving into it I still want an answer about Flash (due to install base) and Silverlight (.NET already used in the project).

Please advice if my findings/assumptions/reasonings are correct.

Thank you.

Comment: was the project ever finished? which technologies did you use? it would be great if you add any useful information as your own answer to this question